# Force www. on multi domain site and retain http or https

Tags: mod-rewrite, htaccess, multiple-domains

I am using CakePHP which already contains an `.htaccess` file that looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to force `www.` (unless it is a subdomain) to avoid duplicate content penalties.

It needs to retain `http` or `https`

Also

This application will have multiple domains pointing to it. So the code needs to be able to work with any domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be evasive about your actual question, but Google was pretty clear that incidental duplication from things like this doesn't cause any penalties with their ranking algorithm:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html

I imagine that most search engines are not dumb enough to penalize the huge majority of sites on the Internet that respond to HTTP hosts with and without the leading "www."

Comment: Well, thats good news. That eliminates my need for this then. Thanks.